# Is it possible to use request.auth in firestore security rules when using a session cookie for authorization?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Consider the following Firestore Security rules

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This uses `request.auth` to check if the requesting user is authenticated. However, this rule fails when I use a sessionCookie for authorization, [as described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies).

Is it impossible to use `request.auth` when using a session cookie? Perhaps that's what's meant by

> For security reasons, Firebase session cookies cannot be used with other Firebase services due to their custom validity period, which can be set to the maximum duration of 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it impossible to use request.auth when using a session cookie?

It is impossible.  Session cookies are a way for passing data between your frontend and your backend, not between your frontend and Firebase backends.  The Firebase SDKs handle the implementation of transfer of auth tokens to Firebase services.

Comment: Hey Doug, the [session cookie docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#sign_in) suggest that we sign out the user if/when using a session cookie to avoid maintaining two copies of the user's auth state.. I'm starting to think there may be good reason to keep both (so that both the server and client know the auth state of the user). Can you elaborate on this? Is it **absolutely** a bad idea to keep both, or is it okay as long as we're *careful* about keeping them in sync?